# static variables appear null outside of main method

Tags: java, arrays, static

Im building a lexical/syntex analyzer for class. The problem I am having is when I try to access my static variable "lexems" or "tokens" from a method besides main they are NULL. When I use them in main (such as the lex.printList method) they are fine and filled with data.

Whats going on???

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SyntaxAnalyzer {
    public static int pos = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> lexems = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String nextToken;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LexicalAnalysis lex = new LexicalAnalysis();
        lex.getFile();
        lex.parseText();
        ArrayList<String> lexems = lex.getLexems();
        lex.printList(lexems);
        ArrayList<String> tokens = lex.getTokens();
        lex.printList(tokens);
        //expr();
        lex();

    }


    static void lex(){
        //String lexem = lexems.get(pos);
        //System.out.println(lexem);
        nextToken = tokens.get(pos);
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overriding the **lexems** object with the local one so it is not **static** variable you are modifying inside main function.

To operate on the static one you should do

```
    /*NOTHING HERE!!*/ lexems = lex.getLexems();
    lex.printList(lexems);
    ...
```

The same issue with **tokens** occurs

```
    /*NOTHING HERE!!*/ tokens = lex.getTokens();
    lex.printList(tokens);
    ...
```

Comment: You might also want to point out that the static fields are *not* null, they are empty because of the hiding/overriding. Big difference.

Comment: The term is _shadowing_.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are here:

```
ArrayList<String> lexems = lex.getLexems();
lex.printList(lexems);
ArrayList<String> tokens = lex.getTokens();
```

In you main function you do not modify the static variables but local ones (local in the main function).
Just change it to that:

```
lexems = lex.getLexems();
tokens = lex.getTokens();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another pair of variables in your main method, which happen to have same names as your static variables, and "overshadow" them within the scope of main method.

To fix it, you should not declare new variables, but initialise the existing ones:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LexicalAnalysis lex = new LexicalAnalysis();
    lex.getFile();
    lex.parseText();
    lexems = lex.getLexems();
    lex.printList(lexems);
    tokens = lex.getTokens();
    lex.printList(tokens);
    //expr();
    lex();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help make the difference between the scopes used in your code :

```
public class MyClass{
    private static int myInt;
    public static void main(String[] args){
         int myInt = 6;
         printMyInt();
    }
    static void printMyInt(){ System.out.println(myInt); } // Prints 0 because uses the class field
}
```